# moment.js set time on existing date is not setting the time correctly

Tags: javascript, datetime, typescript, momentjs

```
let end: Date = new Date();
    let h: string = "13";
    let m: string = "20";
    moment(end).set({ hour: parseInt(h, 10), minute: parseInt(m, 10) });
```

I am trying to set time on an existing date. however the above doe is not setting the time in the date. The time always comes as ...00:00:...

Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: `moment(end)` makes a new Moment object with a new Date buried inside it. Changes to that won't affect the original Date instance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to convert your moment to a `Date`, and assign that `Date` object to your `end` variable:

```
end = moment(end)
    .set({ hour: parseInt(h, 10), minute: parseInt(m, 10) })
    .toDate();
```

Comment: You can go with just `parseInt(h)`. Default radix is 10.

Comment: @adolfosrs [Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified, usually defaulting the value to 10.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)